# Extract row on basis of a column value in a CSV file in bash

Tags: bash, shell, csv, scripting

I am a beginner in scripting and wanted to find how can i possibly find a full row on basis of column values.
I have found a code
`awk -F, '$1=="abc"' filename.csv`
but the twist is here the abc might be stored in a variable and in that case it is not working because ' ' in case of bash doesnt recognise the variable.
Any help would be greatly appreciated